# How to convert text to pojo by SEPARATOR

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a string text, the formatter like `CODE@NAME`, and the `NAME` maybe a null value, just like below text:

```
202304110940436402@SHX01,202304110940477328@,202304110940494662@SHXZ20
```

The pojo:

```java
public class Project {
    String code;
    String name;
    String type;
    String model;
// other property
// getter and setter
}
```

I convert string to 'Project' like this:

```java
String text = "202304110940436402@SHX01,202304110940477328@,202304110940494662@SHXZ20";
Optional<List<Project>> optional = Optional.of(text)
        .map(s -> s.split(COMMA))
        .map(list -> {
            List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>(list.length);
            for (String pojo : list) {
                String[] split = pojo.split(AT, -1);
                Project project = new Project();
                project.code = split[0];
                project.name = split[1];
                projects.add(project);
            }
            return projects;
        });
List<Project> projects = optional.orElse(null);
```

The question is that the string text changed now(such like `CODE@NAME@TYPE@MODEL`).

Now the text like this:

```
202304110940436402@JCSH001,202304110940477328@CGXZ01@8,202304110940494662@@46,202304111152056491@CGXZ01@8@REPEAT, 202304101953270605@XCG@23@
```

I want to parse it like:

```
202304110940436402@JCSH001  -> code:202304110940436402,name:JCSH001 
202304110940477328@CGXZ01@8  -> code:202304110940477328,name:CGXZ01,type:8
202304110940494662@@46  -> code:202304110940494662,name:,type:46
202304111152056491@CGXZ01@8@REPEAT -> code:202304111152056491,name:CGXZ01,type:8, model:REPEAT
```

I have no clue to solve it,so is there have any simple way to convert it and also **compatible with previous content**?

Comment: Please show some examples of input and what you expect to get from that.

Comment: I edited it, i give some input examples in the last, I expect to get pojo of `Project`  by parse text, BTW,  the parse method also compatible with previous content.

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to happen when the input is `202304110940436402@JCSH001,202304110940477328@CGXZ01@8,202304110940494662@@46,202304111152056491@CGXZ01@8@REPEAT, 202304101953270605@XCG@23@`? Please be as specific as possible. Ideally create a [mcve] somewhere like http://ideone.com

Comment: What is the project "code" and "name" from each project in `202304110940436402@JCSH001,202304110940477328@CGXZ01@8,202304110940494662@@46,202304111152056491@CGXZ01@8@REPEAT, 202304101953270605@XCG@23@`?

Comment: The text formatter is like `CODE@NAME@TYPE@MODEL`,  then `202304110940436402@JCSH001` will parse "code" and "name", `202304110940477328@CGXZ01@8` will parse "code","name" and "type", and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `switch` on the length:

```
List<Project> projects = Arrays.stream(text.split(COMMA))
  .map(s -> s.split(AT))
  .map(arr -> {
    Project project = new Project();
    switch (arr.length) {
        case 4: project.setModel(arr[3]);
        case 3: project.setType(arr[2]);
        case 2: project.setName(arr[1]);
        case 1: project.setCode(arr[0]);
    }
    return project;
  })
  .collect(toList());
```

This makes good use of the [*fall through*](https://www.javatpoint.com/fall-through-in-java) behaviour of the switch.

You don't need `Optional` - the resulting list will be empty if there are no items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right path already and are probably overthinking things.

If I understand it correctly you want to parse a comma seperated array into a list of String and parse said Strings into @ seperated Strings.

In the original version we have the CODE@NAME String, later there was a change where it was CODE@NAME@TYPE@MODEL.

You already have the data to get where you need to go, namely your split on @. You need to check how many Strings come out of that split and than assign your values to the Project object.

What I would do is this:

```
Optional<List<Project>> optional = Optional.of(text)
            .map(s -> s.split(COMMA))
            .map(list -> {
                List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String s: list) {
                    String[] split = s.split(AT);
                    Project project = null;
                    if (split.length == 2) {
                        project = new Project();
                        project.setCode(split[0]);
                        project.setName(split[1]);
                    } else if (split.length == 4) {
                        project = new Project();
                        project.setCode(split[0]);
                        project.setName(split[1]);
                        project.setType(split[2]);
                        project.setModel(split[3]);
                    }
                    if(project != null) projects.add(project);
                }
```

There are more efficient and prettier code paths to take but I think what you need right now is verbosity since you are still learning. Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regular Expression matching to extract values.  E.g.

```
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([^@]*)(?:(?:@([^@]*))?(?:(?:@([^@]*))?(?:(?:@([^@]*))?)))$");

        String text = "202304110940436402@JCSH001,202304110940477328@CGXZ01@8,202304110940494662@@46,202304111152056491@CGXZ01@8@REPEAT, 202304101953270605@XCG@23@";
        List<Project> projects = Stream.of(Optional.of(text).orElse("").split(",")).map(s -> {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            if (m.find()) {
                Project proj = new Project();
                proj.code = m.group(1);  //Assuming code will always be there
                proj.name = m.group(2);  //Assuming name will always be there
                if (m.groupCount() > 2) {
                    proj.type = m.group(3);
                    if (m.groupCount() > 3) {
                        proj.model = m.group(4);
                    }
                }
                return proj;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).toList();
```

This results in something like this - Converted Project into a JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "code": "202304110940436402",
        "name": "JCSH001",
        "type": "null",
        "model": "null"
    },
    {
        "code": "202304110940477328",
        "name": "CGXZ01",
        "type": "8",
        "model": "null"
    },
    {
        "code": "202304110940494662",
        "name": "",
        "type": "46",
        "model": "null"
    },
    {
        "code": "202304111152056491",
        "name": "CGXZ01",
        "type": "8",
        "model": "REPEAT"
    },
    {
        "code": " 202304101953270605",
        "name": "XCG",
        "type": "23",
        "model": ""
    }
]
```

You can enhance further.